# Shifting graphics vertically within figure

Tags: includegraphics

I'm sure this is answered somewhere. I've looked, but still having trouble getting exactly what I'm trying to do. Perhaps I need to use something I'm not familiar with. I'm trying to shift one of two graphics within a figure vertically, without changing the bounds of the entire figure itself.

Here is my default code and close to desired result:

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\hspace{-0.25in}\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{img/a.png}~
\hspace{-0.75in}\frame{\includegraphics[width=0.175\textwidth]{img/b.jpg}}
\end{center}
\caption[stuff]{\label{fig:stuff}Some stuff.}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

I am trying to shift the right graphic up vertically a little bit:
[image]

If I adjust with vspace positively/negatively like so, it increases/decreases space between the whole figure and the caption, instead of moving just the right graphic:

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\hspace{-0.25in}\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{img/a.png}~
\hspace{-0.75in}\vspace{0.25in}\frame{\includegraphics[width=0.175\textwidth]{img/b.jpg}}
\end{center}
\caption[stuff]{\label{fig:stuff}Some stuff.}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

How can I shift the right graphics up within the bounds of the figure without changing the space between the entire figure and the caption?

Comment: For future readers, I went down this rabbit hole because my background image had too much surrounding white space in it. Having removed that, any adjusting was no longer necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve the following using the [`overpic` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/overpic):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{overpic}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering   
  \begin{overpic}[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-a}
     \put(65,10){\includegraphics[width=0.175\textwidth]{example-image-b}}  
  \end{overpic}
\caption[stuff]{\label{fig:stuff}Some stuff.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The horizontal and vertical position of the smalle image can be changed by adjusting the values of `x` and `y` in `\put(x,y)`.

Comment: This is great, but now the first graphic has been centered. I had it hspace'd negatively so it looks left aligned. Can I insert a negative hspace somewhere to do that? Or equivalent option for the overpic?

Comment: @delrocco: To left-align the image, simply remove the `\centering` command. If this does not result in the output you want to achive, please clarify.

Comment: That doesn't put it on the left for some reason. However, including package `adjustbox` and adding the option `left` did work. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @leandriis +1 for your code. Is it important, for your opinion, to edit your answer with adjustbox and left as the comment of delrocco?